# Random documents from Elastic Search 7.6.2 - Deprecation Warning message

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to fetch random 6 records which shows the results but gives Deprecation warning message in **7.6.2**

**Below is the query**

```
GET audio,video/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "title"
  ],
  "size": 6,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 1376773391128418000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the warning message from kibana.

## ! Deprecation: As of version 7.0 Elasticsearch will require that a [field] parameter is provided when a [seed] is set

## ! Deprecation: Loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of your documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of Elasticsearch 7.0, it is required to provide a field that can add uniqueness to the random seed generated. If we don't specify any field, it uses _id field by default but that requires the fielddata to be loaded. Since fielddata are considered memory intensive, it is advised to use any other field from the body of the document instead of _id field when using random_score (field like seq_no as provided in elastic documentation)

As mentioned for above reason (memory intensive), it is not recommended to use _id for sorting or aggregation and the same data can be added in the body of the document as keyword field. Generally it's better to avoid sorting or aggregation on text fields as they use fielddata on those fields.

These queries are still allowed only for the backward compatibility and its better to update your code as they would be removed in future releases.

More info:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

**UPDATE** 
Random score using field.

```
GET audio,video/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "title"
  ],
  "size": 6,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 1376773391128418000,
        "field": id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do we specify other field for randomness ..  can you give some sample code

Comment: added a sample query based on your question. Since you have id field in the body of the document, you can use that field for random scoring.

Comment: as it's not working, still giving the deprecation warning